seahorse build Error: anchor-spl v0.30.0 error[E0308]: mismatched types
I'm testing the test case program for the Seahorse architecture calculator.py and everything works fine when I test with beta.solpg.io, and when I test with a local environment I get an error.
My local test environment is as follows:
seahorse = “0.20.0”
anchor-lang = "0.30.0"
solana-program = "1.18.8"
The error log is very long, and it reads as follows:
        If you want to help the project, you can report this:
      - as a Github issue (https://github.com/solana-developers/seahorse/issues).
    
    Thanks![0m
    
       Compiling anchor-spl v0.30.0
    error[E0308]: mismatched types
      --> src/token_interface.rs:14:28
       |
    14 | static IDS: [Pubkey; 2] = [spl_token::ID, spl_token_2022::ID];
       |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`, found `Pubkey`
       |
       = note: `Pubkey` and `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
    note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
      --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
    note: `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
      --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
       = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
    
    error[E0308]: arguments to this function are incorrect
      --> src/associated_token.rs:11:14
       |
    11 |     let ix = spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
       |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    12 |         ctx.accounts.payer.key,
       |         ---------------------- expected `Pubkey`, found `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
    13 |         ctx.accounts.authority.key,
       |         -------------------------- expected `Pubkey`, found `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
    14 |         ctx.accounts.mint.key,
       |         --------------------- expected `Pubkey`, found `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
    15 |         ctx.accounts.token_program.key,
       |         ------------------------------ expected `Pubkey`, found `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey`
       |
       = note: `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` and `Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
    note: `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
      --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
    note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
      --> src/pubkey.rs:96:1
       = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `solana_program` are being used?
       = note: `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` and `Pubkey` have similar names, but are actually distinct types
    note: `anchor_lang::prelude::Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
      --> src/pubkey.rs:88:1
    note: `Pubkey` is defined in crate `solana_program`
.......

1  + use spl_associated_token_account::solana_program::program_pack::Pack;
   |

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `anchor_lang::error::Error`
  --> src/token_interface.rs:98:79
   |
95 | ) -> anchor_lang::Result<T> {
   |      ---------------------- expected `anchor_lang::error::Error` because of this
...
98 |         StateWithExtensions::<spl_token_2022::state::Mint>::unpack(&mint_data)?;
   |                                                                               ^ the trait `From<spl_associated_token_account::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::error::Error`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<ErrorCode>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<ProgramErrorWithOrigin>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<anchor_lang::error::AnchorError>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<std::io::Error>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError>>
   = note: required for `std::result::Result<T, anchor_lang::error::Error>` to implement `FromResidual<std::result::Result<Infallible, spl_associated_token_account::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `anchor_lang::error::Error`
  --> src/token_interface.rs:99:67
   |
95 | ) -> anchor_lang::Result<T> {
   |      ---------------------- expected `anchor_lang::error::Error` because of this
...
99 |     let extension_data = *mint_with_extension.get_extension::<T>()?;
   |                                                                   ^ the trait `From<spl_associated_token_account::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>` is not implemented for `anchor_lang::error::Error`
   |
   = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
   = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<ErrorCode>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<ProgramErrorWithOrigin>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<anchor_lang::error::AnchorError>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<std::io::Error>>
             <anchor_lang::error::Error as From<anchor_lang::prelude::ProgramError>>
   = note: required for `std::result::Result<T, anchor_lang::error::Error>` to implement `FromResidual<std::result::Result<Infallible, spl_associated_token_account::solana_program::program_error::ProgramError>>`

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0277, E0308, E0599.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `anchor-spl` (lib) due to 213 previous errors


try matching your environment to the versions on the solana playground.

anchor_spl is currently broken because of the new Solana Version being released and breaking things in the solana program library (spl). You can track the issue in anchor here and in solana here. If you have access to the Cargo.lock file you can fix this by going through it and replacing every instance of a solana dependency using solana 2.0.1/2.0.0 with 1.18.8 (or whichever version you're using).

To fix this problem, you can downgrade Solana v2 dependencies by manually editing your lock file or simply running:
cargo update -p solana-zk-token-sdk@2.0.1 --precise 1.18.17

